# Is it possible to get x and y coordinates in gazebo world with mouse click?

Tags: ros-melodic, python, gazebo-9

I want to get the coordinates of a point (x and y coordinates) using the mouse on the gazebo client to navigate my robot to this clicked point. Please help me, I'm newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any (official) *existing* functionality to accomplish this functionality in Gazebo "out of the box". If you are brave and willing to write a Gazebo-ROS plugin, [Gazebo supports GUI Plugins](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gui_overlay&cat=user_input) and [System Plugins](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=system_plugin&cat=write_plugin) and there are a few ways to get mouse events (e.g. [this](https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/blob/fc2643c139a9f9627f235295c760a6afc348b0af/gazebo/rendering/Scene.cc#L1208) and  [this](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-gui/blob/c93dd146eb0c3d631bbf7b8ecb0e4f35013a7126/src/plugins/minimal_scene/MinimalScene.cc#L380))

You could also look at what others have previously tried in these Gazebo Answers questions. Both seem highly relevant to what you're looking to do, but mileage may vary with your version of ROS/Gazebo:

- https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/9050/setting-goal-position-with-gazebo/
- https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/5091/get-mouse-click-location-and-event/

Otherwise, the typical ROS approach is to set goals from RViz. This *is* supported "out of the box" and you will find plenty of tutorials/help to get that working (e.g. [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack)).